# send multi destination calls from twilow api using python?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I want to send multiple numbers to multiple destinations using the Twilow API from a text file that contains the numbers.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse

account_sid = 'AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx'
auth_token = '1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
call = client.calls.create(
        to=["+176XXXXX"],
        from_=["+17123XXX"],
        url="http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"
)

print(call)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "send multi numbers to multi destinations"? What is with the code you've posted?

Comment: @AlexBaban  (send multiple numbers to multiple destinations ) ,I want a code to send many calls using numbers(from different destinations) in a text file .